# virtual contiguous addresses and scattergather

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

I have queries regarding memory addressing and scatter(sg) list,please can some one help me with the following:

Q#1:
if page size is 4096 ,let us assume a scenario like below

page0 --- 0-3096 bytes are used and 1000 bytes are free
page1 --- 0-3096 bytes are used and 1000 bytes are free
page2 --- 0-3096 bytes are used and 1000 bytes are free
pageN --- 0-3096 bytes are used and 1000 bytes are free

so if I request for memory of 1010 may be using malloc,will it fail since none of the page has more then 1000 bytes or does it allocates the memory by collecting(accumulative) from multiple pages like page0 (1000bytes) + page1 (10) bytes ?

Q#2:
if page size is 4096 ,then for a given page virtual addresses staring from 0-4096 are guaranteed to be physically contiguous?

## 3:

if i get a data in scatterlist within a page size (may 4096) , does it mean is not really scattered across physical memory ,since it is less than or equal(<=) to a single page size?

BR,
& Sanumala

Answer (score 1):

TL;dr:  It depends.

There are several memory allocation interfaces in the linux kernel, which have varying properties.

One such interface is `kmalloc`, which returns physically contiguous memory (see also this answer: [Linux kernel memory management, does it use consecutive memory pages all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645513/linux-kernel-memory-management-does-it-use-consecutive-memory-pages-all-the-tim/22216223#22216223)).

And there is `vmalloc`, which returns virtually contiguous memory that could extend over multiple non-physically contiguous pages.

There are numerous other memory allocation variants allowing you to allocate small blocks of memory for your own use, or large blocks to be used on behalf of user processes, or multiple pages for use with DMA to/from devices, or a combination of these.

For your other questions, IIUC, memory *within a single page* is always physically contiguous by definition. (For example, if page size is 4096 [0x1000] and you allocate 0x100 bytes and get back an address with 0xb00 in the low digits, it is impossible that it is not physically contiguous.) For allocations that might cross a page boundary -- that is, where `start_address & PAGE_MASK != end_address & PAGE_MASK` -- it would depend on which allocation interface you used.

Scatter-gather is a general concept that describes I/O to/from multiple areas that are not definitely known to be physically contiguous. That could either be intra-kernel only (i.e. `struct scatterlist` is specifically there to manage multi-part non-physically-contiguous memory), or it could mean the `iovec` used to support `readv`/`writev`. In the latter case, a user is entitled to request a scatter-gather operation that has a region starting at XXXXX004 for a length of 10 bytes plus another region at YYYYY300 for 20 bytes. XXXXX and YYYYY might be the same or or they might be different. *If* they are the same, then yes, you can be assured that they are within the same physical page (again, *iff* either length does not cross a page boundary).

If by `malloc` you actually mean the user space library function, that memory can only be assumed to be physically contiguous to the extent that the length doesn't span a page boundary (and in fact, it could change at any moment -- the kernel is free at any time to steal a page, writing its content to the paging space ["swap" partition], and later restore a different physical page in its place, reading the content back from the paging space without the process being aware of it).